# Emacs org-mode: how to determine, that the current node was clocked in

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

Suppose, we have an org file like this:

```
* TODO Write function x
```

I want to clock the time working on it. There are 2 functions in org mode:

1. org-clock-in
2. org-clock-out

I decided to combine them in this manner:

```
(defun org-set-clock ()
  "Clock current node in/out"
  (if (<current node is not clocked in>))
    (org-clock-in)
    (org-clock-out)
  )
```

And attach this function to a simple shortcut:

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "M-q") 'org-set-clock)))
```

How to write this code: `<current node is not clocked in>`?

Answer (score 3):

Below you can find an updated solution.

```lisp
(defun org-set-clock ()
  "One-off function for `org-mode' task clocking.

Behaviour:
* When there is no running clock, start
  the clock for the item at point.
* When there is already a running clock and
  `point' is at the item which is being clocked
  stop the corresponding clock.
* When there is already a running clock but `point'
  is not at the item which is being clocked,
  stop the clock and restart it for item at `point'."
  (interactive)
  (let ((interrupting (and (not org-clock-resolving-clocks-due-to-idleness)
               (org-clocking-p))))
    (if interrupting
    (if (save-excursion
          (org-back-to-heading t)
          (and (equal (marker-buffer org-clock-hd-marker)
              (current-buffer))
           (= (marker-position org-clock-hd-marker)
              (point))
           (equal org-clock-current-task (nth 4 (org-heading-components)))))
        (org-clock-out)
      (org-clock-in))
      (org-clock-in))))
```

**Edit:** If you are unable to update `org-mode` to a sufficiently recent version, you can use

```lisp
(defun org-set-clock ()
  "One-off function for `org-mode' task clocking.

    Behaviour:
    * When there is no running clock, start
      the clock for the item at point.
    * When there is already a running clock and
      `point' is at the item which is being clocked
      stop the corresponding clock.
    * When there is already a running clock but `point'
      is not at the item which is being clocked,
      stop the clock and restart it for item at `point'."
  (interactive)
  (if (org-clocking-p)
      (if (save-excursion
        (org-back-to-heading t)
        (and (equal (marker-buffer org-clock-hd-marker)
            (current-buffer))
         (= (marker-position org-clock-hd-marker)
            (point))
         (equal org-clock-current-task (nth 4 (org-heading-components)))))
      (org-clock-out)
    (org-clock-in))
    (org-clock-in)))
```

however, I'd recommend using the `org-mode` [`elpa`](http://orgmode.org/elpa.html) which'll keep you always up to date.

Comment: Seems, that `org-clock-resolving-clocks-due-to-idleness` is undefined in my org-mode. I'll try to update it. I didn't understand your question. Can you explain it in more details?

Comment: @user4035 I'm using the most recent `org-mode` with version `8.2.8`. Okay, so assume you are already clocking some task. Now you go to some `org-mode` buffer and move the curser (`point`) on some other task and execute the function. It will not check, whether the cursor is over the task which is currently being clocked. It will stop **any** running task. If there is no running task, it will start clocking the one, the cursor is over.

Comment: It would be better, if it checked, whether the current task is clocked.

Comment: So what should it do if a task is being clocked but the cursor is on a different task?

Comment: It should do clock-in for the new task

Comment: @user4035 Updated the code, could you check that it behaves as desired?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it on Windows machine with org-mode 7.9.3f. But `org-clock-resolving-clocks-due-to-idleness` is undefined. Is it possible to do without it or I'll need to upgrade?